# How to search a string inside a string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A with columns Country ID ,Country. and data is like this

```
US United States
IN India
JP Japan
NP Nepal
```

etc .
I have different table B which has a column Country which mostly has free text data . Data is like

```
Texas United States 
India KA
XYS Japan WYS 
EverestNepal  
XYZ
```

etc.

What i want is that if country column in Table B has a country matching from any column of country in Table A , it should return Country from Table A.

So for the example i gave
Table B has Texas United States --- there is a match in Table A with 'United States' : It should print United States

Table B has India KA ---- there is a match in Table A with 'India':it should print India

EverestNepal --- there is a match in Table A with 'Nepal': it should print Nepal
Table B has 
and so on.

To summarize : If the exact match of country in Table B from anywhere in the string is found in Table A, it should print country from Table A
I dont think Like , IN , Substring will work in such situation

Answer (score 1):

`INSTR` (line #17) is what you probably need.

```
SQL> with
  2  ta (country_id, country) as
  3    (select 'US', 'United States' from dual union all
  4     select 'IN', 'India'         from dual union all
  5     select 'JP', 'Japan'         from dual union all
  6     select 'NP', 'Nepal'         from dual
  7    ),
  8  tb (country) as
  9    (select 'Texas United States' from dual union all
 10     select 'India KA'            from dual union all
 11     select 'XYS Japan WYS'       from dual union all
 12     select 'EverestNepal'        from dual union all
 13     select 'XYZ'                 from dual
 14    )
 15  select b.country B_country,
 16         a.country A_country
 17  from ta a right join tb b on instr(b.country, a.country) > 0;

B_COUNTRY           A_COUNTRY
------------------- -------------
Texas United States United States
India KA            India
XYS Japan WYS       Japan
EverestNepal        Nepal
XYZ

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` operator to join between the tables:

```
SELECT
    A.COUNTRY
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    JOIN TABLE_B B ON ( A.COUNTRY LIKE '%'
                                       || B.COUNTRY
                                       || '%' );
```

Cheers!!